# before action in symfony2

Tags: symfony, before-filter

I want to check whether a user is logged before calling most of the methods in my web application. I don't know how to do that. I want something like before_filter in Ruby On Rails. I have checked the before filter in the symfony2 documentation but it does not help me. I need a real life example for the login.

This is the link I have checked. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to handle access control in Symfony. The most basic is with URL matching, which is handy when you want to restrict access to a URL like /admin and anything that follows. This is configured in security.yml.

```
# app/config/security.yml 
security: 
    access_control: 
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

This page shows the different ways to secure your application:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#access-control

There is even a way to secure any service even if it's not a controller:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/securing_services.html

Comment: but how can i check id there is already a session or not? in another word: if the user is logged in, allow access, otherwise, redirect to the login page

Comment: If your user is logged in he most likely has the ROLE_USER role (the basic role that any logged in user has), so you can require that role in the access control pattern. Symfony will handle redirecting if the user doesn't have the role.

Comment: I still get: Full authentication is required to access this resource.  so I should not care here about storing sessions? and what about redirection? I want to redirect the user if he is not logged in

Comment: You'll need to elaborate on what you are actually doing in order to know what that message comes from.  As I said before, if you secure a request and the user is not logged in, the user is automatically redirected to the login page.  I would thoroughly read the first link I posted in the answer.

Comment: thanks, I have solved the issue. I needed to understand better that "Role" concept in symfony.